# Can I fly with a robot as a passenger instead of shipping it as luggage?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, legal, seating

Can I book a ticket for my C-3PO human-size figure and let it have a seat instead of paying extra money to have it shipped?

I couldn't find a law which says the passenger has to have a soul, its all about his dimensions

I'll be flying with Ryanair from London to Glasgow

Comment: On my last flight with RyanAir  a musician had booked a seat for her upright bass, so they don't seem to have a problem with selling seats for lugagge (but they do have a help center on their website, so it might be easier to ask there).

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22679/how-do-i-travel-with-musical-instruments, also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-can-i-fly-with-a-guitar

Comment: Although related, this is not a duplicate of the linked questions.

Comment: If this is allowed (and I really hope it is) you should take a selfie with your humanoid companion and post it as an update.

Comment: Btw while I do not want to denigrate your faith into the force (got myself premiere tickets, yeah !) even in-universe C3Po would classify as baggage. The reason souls are not mentioned in the terms of service is that inanimate objects are by definition baggage, not passengers (possible exceptions for Transsilvanian airlines and other related jokes). You cannot catch airlines with semantic wordplays (and you should by prepared for a long walk if you try).

Comment: I got an extra seat for my guitar (in a flightcase) on Ryanair, they just made me give it a window seat for safety (so nobody has to climb over it in the event of an emergency)

Comment: The force is strong with this question.

Comment: How much does it weight?

Comment: @EikePierstorff You're assuming it's not a fully-functional battlestation, eh, robot. If it can move independently it's different question -- probably needs it's own passport tho'. I'd just find a nearby Wookie to tear the arms off and pack it as checked luggage, they appear to be used to that.

Comment: Be prepared for a thorough inspection by TSA, especially if your figure contains metal. Unless you can pull off the "these are not the droids you are looking for" jedi trick...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni You'd have to have a really weird connection to be screened by TSA on a flight from London to Glasgow. :) London to Glasgow via New York, perhaps. Although I don't think you'll be flying Ryanair on that route. *shudders at the thought*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Probably not (but  it does not hurt to ask).

RyanAir as actually a Q/A section that answers the question "can i book a seat for my luggage". If taken verbatim this seems to apply almost exclusively to musical instruments, you would need to ask if your CP30 falls under those exceptions. However they give maximum dimensions, so if your robot exceeds those you already have your answer.

From [Ryanair's website](https://contactform.ryanair.com/?cr=2-6&lg=en&id=32#regulations-checkedbaggage).

> Sporting or musical equipment including but not limited to large
>   fishing rods, golf clubs, bikes* (bikes have a weight limit of 30
>   kilos), scooters, fencing equipment, boules, pole vaults, javelin,
>   surfboards, bodyboards, snowboards and skis and large musical
>   instruments including but not limited to harps, double bass and drums
>   are inherently unsuitable for carriage by airlines operating fast
>   turnarounds such as Ryanair. However, these items may be carried in
>   the hold of the aircraft in addition to your personal checked baggage
>   allowance up to a limit of 20 kilos per item. Fees apply, click here
>   for details.
>
> Any sporting and musical item weighing over the 20 kilos allowance
>   will be charged for the excess at the applicable excess baggage rate
>   per kilo.
>
> - Bicycles - MUST be contained in a protective box or protective bike bag in order to be accepted for travel. Electric bicycles cannot be
>     transported by plane.
>
> Smaller musical items such as a guitar, violin or viola which exceed
>   our cabin baggage dimensions may be carried in the cabin if a seat for
>   it has been reserved and the appropriate fare paid. There is no
>   checked or cabin baggage allowance associated with the purchase of an
>   extra seat.
>
> To book an extra seat for an item the word "ITEM SEAT" must be entered
>   as the surname and "EXTRA" must be entered at the first name. EXTRA
>   ITEM SEAT will then be displayed on the reservation and online
>   boarding pass. The accompanying passenger's travel document details
>   must be entered during the online check- in process. Reserved seating
>   in emergency rows 1,16 and 17 may not be purchased if you have
>   purchased an extra seat for item/comfort.
>
> **For health and safety reasons Ryanair does not accept for carriage any
>   individual item exceeding 32 kilos or with combined dimensions of more
>   than 81cms (height), 119cms (width) and 119cms (depth)**. This weight
>   limit does not apply to mobility equipment.

Comment: You could try to claim that your Threepio is a music instrument -- after all, if you bang on it, it makes a nice metallic sound, right?

Answer (score 5):

One potential issue is that you might have to put your metallic friend through the X-ray scanner, and I'm not sure these are normally large enough to take a human-sized object. Security might also demand to open him up, to check for explosives etc. This would be especially true if he has a metallic casing that prevents the scanners from seeing inside.

Comment: Checked luggage is also x-rayed to check for bombs, so that's not a problem unique to going through security.