# Can I fly with a Christmas turkey on a domestic flight within the UK?

Tags: air-travel, uk, airport-security

Slaughtered, obviously and in a cool box.

[image]

Comment: If the box is of allowed carry-on baggage size and doesn't use dry ice, then it might be okay. Dry ice is a restricted item according to IATA Dangerous goods regulations.

Comment: @Egil I was thinking of removing all the ice before the security then buy ice from the shops after the security

Comment: If you're sure you'll be able to get some ice inside, then you should be fine, except maybe for a few puzzled looks from airport security. another option could be using portable car refrigerator - I've seen one passenger dragging one of those along to the plane to keep his duty-free bought beers cool.

Comment: @Egil sounds like a very good idea! I'll do a quick research about them, thanks

Comment: As carry-on, or in checked baggage?

Comment: @jpatokal hand luggage, I usually travel with no luggage at all, except a phone charger and a wallet.

Comment: and a bazooka, and a gold bar, and a turkey, and a knife, and a bullet-proofed vest, ...

Comment: @RoflcoptrException how did you know about the knife? it was a Swiss army knife and was before 9/11, the officers were nice back then, he only explained to me with a big smile that there is no way I can fly with this tool, I was very late and I immediately told him he can have it even when it was a gift from my grandfather but I couldn't afford even few seconds. I ran like a crazy to the airplane as they were shouting my name.. gosh what a memory

Comment: Personally, I'd probably just find a decent butcher at the far end, and buy the turkey on arrival...

Comment: @Gagravarr have you noticed the word "slaughtered"?

Comment: @Joulupukki If it hadn't been slaughtered, then it comes under transporting live animals, which is an entirely different question! Especially as the UK, unlike the USA, doesn't have [Comfort Animals / Emotional Support Animals](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2014/10/20/pets-allowed) so you'll struggle to take your live turkey with you as an ESA on the flight...

Comment: @Gagravarr what meant is that you can't get a slaughtered turkey easily in the UK, hence I'll fly with it from London

Comment: In all seriousness, it's hard to think of a coolbox that could both fit a turkey and fit within most airline carry-on restrictions. So you may need to buy it a seat http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58773/can-i-fly-with-a-robot-as-a-passenger-instead-of-shipping-it-as-luggage

Comment: You can get meat (including turkey) delivered anywhere in the UK. Google 'online butcher' and take your pick. If you must have that specific turkey then ship it 24-hour courier sealed with insulation and ice packs, like the internet butchers do.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

As long as you buy a ticket for it and have it treated like a pet (so pet carrier, have it travel in the hold with the other pets) I see little reason why not.

Of course dead pets might cause some raised eye brows with the pet handlers...

Comment: Wow, so many downvotes...

Comment: Because it's almost certainly wrong. I don't think butchered meat products are going to be treated as pets somehow.

Comment: @CMaster It was more that none of them had commented to explain why. At least you did :/

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can't do it **out** of the United Kingdom:

We have precedence, where [security in Cardiff airport confiscated a frozen turkey from luggage](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/article-1342727/Frozen-turkey-confiscated-Cardiff-Airport-unusual-hand-luggage-items-revealed.html), as "perishable goods cannot be transported abroad without permission.".

Now this was for an international flight, but within the EU region, so I wouldn't be surprised if it applied domestically as well.  However, as the article itself points out at the end, for unusual items like this, it's always best to call the airline in advance.

Comment: I wonder whether the Cardiff security staff actually got that right. [There are no general restrictions on carrying meat within the EU](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/carry/meat-dairy-animal/index_en.htm), and the UK [allows people to bring meat for personal consumption into the country from other EU countries](http://www.food.gov.uk/sites/default/files/multimedia/pdfs/pdf-ni/dard-personal.pdf).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I also wondered that. But given it made the news and there were no lawyers going 'oi, that's wrong', I guess they've got it on their side :/  Either that or not enough turkey fans protesting.