# Traveling with guitar on AirEuropa

Tags: air-travel, luggage, hand-luggage, music

Anyone has any experience traveling on AirEuropa, long and short distance, with guitars? What are the enforced restrictions? Can I carry it with me?

Comment: Highly related: *[How do I travel with musical instruments?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22679)* and *[How can I fly with a guitar?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1031)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the Air Europa webpage on special baggage, musical instruments and other non-standard luggage are subject to restrictions.](http://aea.aireuropa.com/waeam/bn/estaticos/guia_pasajero/equipaje_especiales.html) If the instrument size is less than 115 cm you can take it on-board as your one piece of hand-luggage. If the size is larger than 115cm you can either put it in the hold by paying a fee, or place it on another seat that you'll have to purchase separately.

Quoting from the linked website:

> [image: Air Europa webpage on special baggage]

Of particular interest is this part:

> **Note (6): Musical instruments "<115 cm"** can be taken on-board as conventional cabin baggage at no extra cost providing they are carried instead of the single piece of hand luggage allowed per person.
>
> **Note (7): Musical instruments "> 115 cm"** should go in hold paying a supplement of € 150 or you can take it with you in cabin on a seat by paying the price of the additional space.